# Unable to decipher "error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've been looking around and haven't come up with any tangible solutions. It sounds like it is looking for a default constructor instead of the one in place but I have one below. Moving it up as the first listed constructor didn't change the error messages so I'm wrong about that. Here's the full error message (using jGRASP):

```
In file included from intset.h:47:0,
                 from IntSet.cpp:1:
IntSet.cpp:12:11: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
    IntSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
           ^
IntSet.cpp:12:11: error: expected ')' before 'int'
```

Here's the IntSet.cpp code:

```
#include "intset.h"
//#include <algorithm>
//#include <iostream>

    int size;
    const int MAXSIZE = 25000;
    bool set[MAXSIZE];
    const int SENTINEL = -1;


    //Constructors
   IntSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
      size = a;

      if(b > size) {
            size = b;
        }
        if(c > size) {
            size = c;
        }
        if(d > size) {
            size = d;
        }
        if(e > size) {
            size = e;
        }

        set = new bool[size];
        for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            if(i == a || i == b || i == c || i == d || i == e) {
                insert(i);
            } else {
                remove(i);
            }
        }
   }

    IntSet(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        IntSet(a, b, c, d, -1);
    }

    IntSet(int a, int b, int c) {
        IntSet(a, b, c, -1, -1);
    }

    IntSet(int a, int b) {
        IntSet(a, b, -1, -1, -1);
    }

    IntSet(int a) {
        IntSet(a, -1, -1, -1, -1);
    }

    //Copy constructor
    IntSet(const IntSet& x) {
        size = x.size;
        for (int i = 0; i <= x.size; i++ ) {
            set[i] = x.set[i];
        }
    }

    //Destructor
    ~IntSet()
    {
        //for(int i = this.length(); i >= 0; i--) {
        //  this[i]
        //}
    }

    ////////////////////////

    bool insert(int a) {
        if(a <= size && a >= 0) {
            set[a] = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if(a >= 0) {
            //removed "new" from line below
            IntSet temp = IntSet(a);
            &this += temp;
            set[a] = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool remove (int a) {
        if (isInSet(a)) {
            set[a] = false;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        bool retVal = true;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            if (set[i] == true) {
                retVal = false;
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    bool isInSet (int a) {
        if (set[a]){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    IntSet operator + (IntSet a) {
        IntSet c = IntSet(max(size, a.size));
        for (int i = 0; i <= c.size; i++) {
            if (set[i] || a.set[i]){
                c.set[i] = true;
            }
            else {
                c.set[i] = false;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    IntSet operator * (IntSet a) {
        IntSet c = IntSet(max(size, a.size));
        for (int i = 0; i <= c.size; i++) {
            if (set[i] && a.set[i]) {
                c.set[i] = true;
            }
            else {
                c.set[i] = false;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    IntSet operator - (IntSet a) {
        IntSet c = IntSet();
        c.size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            if (set[i] && !a.set[i]) {
                c.set[i] = true;
            }
            else {
                c.set[i] = false;
            }
            c.size++;
        }
        return c;
    }

    IntSet operator = (const IntSet a) {
        return IntSet(a);
    }

    IntSet operator += (IntSet a) {
        return IntSet(operator+(a));
    }

    IntSet operator *= (IntSet a) {
        return IntSet(operator * (a));
    }

    IntSet operator -= (IntSet a) {
        return IntSet(operator - (a));
    }

    IntSet operator == (const IntSet a) const{
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(set[i] != a.set[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    IntSet operator != (IntSet a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(set[i] != a.set[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    IntSet operator << (IntSet a) {
        cout << "{";
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(set[i]) {
                cout << " " << i;
            }
        }
        cout << "}";
    }

    IntSet operator >> (IntSet a) {
        int index;
        while(cin >> index && index != SENTINEL) {
            insert(index);
        }
    }
```

Here is the attached intset.h code:

```
#ifndef INTSET_H
#define INTSET_H
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class IntSet {

public:
    //Constructors
    IntSet();
    IntSet(int);
    IntSet(int, int);
    IntSet(int, int, int);
    IntSet(int, int, int, int);
    IntSet(int, int, int, int, int);
    IntSet(const IntSet&);  // M: Added the &; must be a pointer or reference
    ~IntSet();

    //Overloaded Operators  M:  Added 'IntSet' in front of the word 'operator.'
    // It was required syntax.
    IntSet operator+(IntSet);
    IntSet operator*(IntSet);
    IntSet operator-(IntSet);
    IntSet operator=(IntSet);
    IntSet operator+=(IntSet);
    IntSet operator*=(IntSet);
    IntSet operator-=(IntSet);
    IntSet operator==(IntSet);
    IntSet operator!=(IntSet);
    IntSet operator<<(IntSet);
    IntSet operator>>(IntSet);

    //Functions
    bool insert(int);
    bool remove(int);
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isInSet(int);

private:
    const int MAXSIZE;
    int size;
    bool set[];
    const int SENTINEL;
};

#include "IntSet.cpp"
#endif
```

I haven't had much experience with header files so it wouldn't surprise me if I formatted something incorrectly but I'm looking at plenty of other samples provided by the professor and there isn't anything unusual about mine. I thought maybe it had something to do with the order listed in the .h file and that I wasn't following the same exact order in the .cpp but nothing changed when I had everything listed in the same order.

Comment: Start by getting this: `#include "IntSet.cpp"` **out** of your header file.

Comment: You say `//constructors` on line 11, but I can't see any class definition. Did you forget to open one? Could this be the issue?

Comment: i guess you are missing the `scopeof (::)` operator before constructor name .

Comment: oh, sweet. You have circular inclusion. No, that won't work as desired.

Comment: @WhozCraig if I remove that out of my header file then they wont link? How's the compiler going to know where the actual code is if I don't tell it.

Comment: If it doesn't link, its because you're not including all source modules in your compilation. A multi-file project needs to compile each source module independently, then link them together.

Comment: I commented that line out of the .h and the header compiles fine. I have some things to address in the .cpp before it'll compile properly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot that is wrong with your code. We are going to have to jump around a bit between the header and the implementation. Ready?

In your header you do this:

```
class IntSet {
    /* stuff */
private:
    bool set[];
};
```

First of all, the name `set` is a bad choice: it is the name of a class in `namespace` `std`w which you are importing by having `using namespace std` in your header file. This can be confusing at best.

More importantly, the syntax `bool set[]` isn't correct in this context. Even if your compiler allows it, it's an extension. Who knows what it does and how it will behave on other compilers? Avoid it.

If you want to declare an array, declare an array. If you want to declare a pointer, declare a pointer. Just remember: **an array isn't a pointer**.

Unfortunately you don't, becase later on in your code you do this:

```
set = new bool[size];
```

What is this supposed to do? `set` isn't a pointer, it's some kind of array, and you cannot assign a pointer to an array.

Now, we get to the second problem: you declare some member variables for your class, in your header file:

```
class IntSet {
/* some stuff here */
private:
    const int MAXSIZE;
    int size;
    bool set[];
    const int SENTINEL;
};
```

Then in your implementation you have the following code floating up at the top:

```
int size;
const int MAXSIZE = 25000;
bool set[MAXSIZE];
const int SENTINEL = -1;
```

I don't think that this does what you think it does. It seems that your intention is to initialize those variables, but that's not what happens. Remember, those variables only exist as members variables that belong to a particular instance of a class, and they are not "free-standing". So what's happening here?

Well, this declares all these variables again, so you have variables called `MAXSIZE`, `size`, `set` and `SENTINEL` that are valid *anywhere* in that translation unit (i.e. the .cpp file), independent of the member variables in the class.

This, of course, means that the member variables with those names aren't initialized (well, except `set` which you assign a pointer to, which we already know is wrong). This will cause your code to exhibit undefined behavior. After all, the value of an uninitialized variable can be anything at all.

If your intention had been to initialize the class members, then you should remove that code and initialize those variables in your constructor(s):

```
IntSet::IntSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) 
    : size(a), MAXSIZE(25000), SENTINEL(-1) 
{
    /* whatever*/ 
}
```

Notice, by the way, how I used `IntSet::` in front of the constructor name? This is called the scope resolution operator. Remember, there is no constructor called `IntSet`. The constructor belongs to a class, which is called `IntSet`, and outside of that class, it's proper name is `IntSet::IntSet`. A small example may help:

```
class Test
{
    int Length;

public:
    /* notice how inside the class, you only need Test 
     * when providing a body for the constructor. This
     * makes sense. You know which class you inside of.
     */
    Test()
        : Length(0)
    {

    }

    Test(int len);
};

/* Now we are outside the class. We need to help 
 * the compiler out and tell it what class the
 * function belongs to.
 */
Test::Test(int len)
    : Length(len)
{
}
```

A tangential point as to do with the names that you are using. What's `a`? Why do you use `a` to initialize something called `size`? You should choose *meaningful* variables names that help document the code so that when you have to read it back your head doesn't explode.

Another tangential point is that if variables like `MAXSIZE` and `SENTINEL` are going to be shared between all instances of the class, then, for future reference, you should probably consider making them `static` class members.

Lastly, you have this bit of code in your header file

```
#include "IntSet.cpp"
```

This is, almost certainly, not correct. You should **never** do this (there may be some who think that there are exceptions, but don't learn bad habits at this point. When you know enough to stumble on this legitimately, then you will know enough to determine whether it's the right thing to do or not).

What makes it worse is that your implementation file contains:

```
#include "IntSet.h"
```

Think about what you are doing here: when the compiler is processing the file `IntSet.h` you are telling to also process the file `IntSet.cpp`. The file `IntSet.cpp` tells the compiler to process the file `IntSet.h`. Which tells the compiler to process the file `IntSet.cpp`. And so on and so forth.

Generally speaking, implementation files (.cpp) will include header files. Header files will only include other header files.

There are a few other issues, but you should probably fix all these things, and then, if you are still having issues, post a new question and we can go from there.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response! The code is messy because I"m learning as I go along and have been trying to correct issues to get it to compile so that I can run preliminary testing and ensure the functions do what I intend them to do.

In the header what I'm trying to do with this line: "bool numList[];" is declare that each instance of the IntSet object will have its own bool array. An issue I'm having is I'm unclear where I should be initializing it "numList[somenumber];" Also there is the potential that I need to recreate the array to allocate memory until a new larger size.

Comment: I thought the #ifndef stuff took care of the circular logic by telling it not to redefine itself but I took out #include "intset.cpp" since it's not necessary (i thought it was so that the header file had actual code backing it).

Yes some of the variable names aren't as descriptive as they could be but the reason for size initializing to 'a' is because that is a constructor that takes in 5 integers. I need my size variable to link to the largest of those 5 integers (which is why all those ugly if statements) and then I need to instantiate a bool arr to that size.

Comment: @MilanNovaković you're welcome - it's always tricky when starting out. If you want to have a `numList` that grows and shrinks, then what you want is to use either a pointer (`bool *numList;`) or, **better yet**, an `std::vector`. The C++ standard library has a wealth of containers that are useful, speed up development and reduce the chance of errors. You should learn how to leverage them.

Comment: The `#ifdef` would, indeed, take care of the circular dependency. I missed it when looking through the code. But that only shows why doing that sort of thing is a bad idea: it's confusing ;)

Comment: I moved the MAXSIZE (temporarily ignoring SENTINEL) to this position. My goal is to have it as a static constant across every instance of the IntSet objects:

'class IntSet {

const static int MAXSIZE = 25000;

public:
 //Constructors
   IntSet(int, int, int, int, int);
   IntSet(int, int, int, int);'

Do I instantiate it to a number in the above position or do I still have to initialize it by the constructor? I hope these comments explained some more of my intentions. I've just been unable to precisely put those intentions down into code (as I'm still learning).

Comment: I have heard of vectors but unfortunately this is an assignment in which I MUST use bool arr to basically keep count of numbers in a set. So when I encounter a number that is larger than my current bool arr I need to dynamically expand the arr to include the number. Since arr can't grow or shrink I thought I could just "assign" a new larger one by using the numList = new bool[NEWNUM];"

Are you saying that in my header file it would be declared as bool *numList[];?

Comment: the `const static int MAXSIZE = 25000` inside the class should be fine; you can do the same with `SENTINEL`. One more general comment: you may be better served by taking a step back an starting from scratch. In a new file, declare a class with no members and add a `main` function. Once that compiles, declare an instance of your class in main. Once that compiles, add a single variable. Rinse, lather, repeat. Add a single thing every time while you get a feel for the language. It sounds tedious, but it will save you a lot of frustration.

Comment: Correct. In C++ arrays have a fixed size and can't be resized. If you array is sized for 77 items that's the most it will ever hold. If  you need something resizable, you need to have a pointer that points to a dynamically allocated array; then when you need to resize, what you do is allocate a new array dynamically (using `new`), copying the old data into this newly allocated array, `delete[]` the old array and set the pointer to point to the new array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the name of the class and `::` before defining a member function.

```
  IntSet::IntSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
//^^^^^^^^
//here
```

Do the same with the other constructors, the operators and methods.

Comment: Before every function including all the operator overloads and constructors?

Comment: Yes, if there is no class name, the compiler thinks it is a global function.

Comment: +1 this is correct to address compilation, but the project structure (including a cpp file in a header file) is still a hack. The OP needs to compile each module correctly, then link them together.

Comment: That seems to have gotten rid of the previous error messages and now I have a different one. Am I supposed to be initializing my constants in my .cpp or .h? I currently have them initializing in my .cpp but I'm getting this error message

"uninitialized member 'IntSet::MAXSIZE' with 'const' type 'const int' [-fpermissive]"